# What is the unit for ground speed reported by ADS-B?

Tags: ads-b, groundspeed, measurement, units

Strangely enough, I'm having trouble finding the unit reported by ADS-B on the Internet. Many sites simply refer to it as "ground speed". Is it measured in KPH?

Comment: FWIW, I googled "ADS-B goundspeed readout". The second entry that came up was for https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC20-172B.pdf. In that document, the only unit I saw for distance was nautical miles, and the only unit I saw for speed was knots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ADS-B* encodes the ground speed in **NM/s** (nautical miles per second) in $2^{15}$ increments of ≅ 0.22 knots each such that:

> 0 ≤ Ground Speed < 2 NM/s

As of June 2015*, it is optional to report the ground speed (users can use two position reports to get the speed). Decoding to Knots (NM/h) is more common though for aviation for most of the world.**

---

[image]

---

* [Eurocontrol Standard Document For Surveillance Data Exchange](https://www.eurocontrol.int/sites/default/files/content/documents/nm/asterix/20150615-asterix-adsbtr-cat021-part12-v2.4.pdf)
** ICAO (Annex 5) recommends km/h but permits the 'temporary use' (as they put it) of non-SI alternative units for vertical/horizontal distances and speed.